PDF file showing after downloading in android kotlin
Hello In the below pdf file is storing in external storage downlaods folder and then trying open the pdf file. But it is not opening.My aim is to downlaod and preview the pdf file
Can any one help me where I did the mistake.
Path :pdfFile:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.goforhrm/files/Download/My_PaySlip/report.pdf
pdfFile:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.goforhrm/files/Download/My_PaySlip/report.pdf
private fun convertByteArrayToPdf(context: Context, byteArray: ByteArray) {
    val fileDir = applicationContext.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
    val directoryName = "My_PaySlip" // Replace with your desired directory name
    val directory = File(fileDir, directoryName)
    if (!directory.exists()) {
        directory.mkdirs()
    }
    val pdfFile = File(directory, "report.pdf") // Replace with desired name
    Log.d("volley", "pdfFile:${pdfFile}")
    try {
        val fos = FileOutputStream(pdfFile)
        fos.write(byteArray)
        fos.close()
        Toast.makeText(this, "File downloaded successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        val mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton()
            .getMimeTypeFromExtension(pdfFile.path.substringAfterLast("."))
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(pdfFile.path), mimeType)
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        startActivity(intent)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Download failed: ${e.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        // Handle exception
    }
}

pdf file to be preview
